# SQL Server stored procedure passing date parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccountsData]  
    @Start_Date datetime,
    @End_Date datetime
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    SELECT 
        a.Customer_AC_No, a.Customer_Name, a.Product_Code, 
        a.Product_Description, a.Sales_Person, c.HSID
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             Customer_AC_No, Customer_Name, Product_Code, 
             Product_Description, Sales_Person
         FROM 
             View_Sales_Details
         WHERE 
             ([Week Ending]  >=' @Start_Date') AND ([Sales Value] > 0)
         GROUP BY 
             Customer_AC_No, Product_Code, Product_Description, 
             Customer_Name, Sales_Person) AS a
   LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT 
            Customer_AC_No, Product_Code
        FROM 
            View_Sales_Details
        WHERE 
            ([Week Ending] >= '@End_Date') AND ([Sales Value] > 0)
        GROUP BY 
            Customer_AC_No, Product_Code) AS b ON a.Customer_AC_No = b.Customer_AC_No
                                               AND a.Product_Code = b.Product_Code
    INNER JOIN 
        Hubspot.dbo.View_BPA_Cust_Data AS c ON a.Customer_AC_No = c.CustomerNo COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
     WHERE 
         b.Customer_AC_No IS NULL 
     ORDER BY  
         a.Customer_AC_No, a.Product_Code ASC
END
```

I am trying to pass the above date parameters to the SQL Server stored procedure above, but I keep getting this error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AccountsData, Line 52
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can some one please help. WeekEnding date is also in datetime format. Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Can you show us the code which is passing the parameters?

Comment: EXEC [dbo].[AccountsData] '2019-05-11 00:00:00','2020-06-10 00:00:00'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server for specifying a date&time as a string literal - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible.

So in your case, either switch to using `DATE` as your parameter datatype (since you obviously don't use the time portion):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccountsData]  
    @Start_Date DATE,
    @End_Date DATE
```

and then execute your stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[AccountsData] '2019-05-11', '2020-06-10'
```

or use this format to support `DATETIME` if you insist on keeping that:

```
EXEC [dbo].[AccountsData] '2019-05-11T00:00:00', '2020-06-10T00:00:00'
```

Comment: Hi Marc,
Thanks for your suggestion's I tried those getting the same error

Comment: @Randy: you also need to **remove** the single quotes in your code where you reference the parameters - so use ` ([Week Ending]  >= @Start_Date)` (**no** single quotes around the parameter!!)

Answer (score 0):

Your have an error in your select. You have change your query like this

```
 DATEPART(wk, Ending)>=DATEPART(wk, @Start_Date) AND ([Sales Value] > 0)
 DATEPART(wk, Ending)>=DATEPART(wk, @End_Date) AND ([Sales Value] > 0)
```